The inverse limit of a sequence of ring surjections commutes with taking difference subsets of the respective units & gluing in some primes?
Define $R_n := \Bbb{Z}/p_n\#$ the ring of integers modulo primorial $p_n\# = p_n p_{n-1} \cdots p_1$.  Let $U_n$ denote the group of units modulo $p_n\#$ in these rings.
Then if $f_{n,n+1}: \Bbb{Z}/p_{n+1}\# \twoheadrightarrow \Bbb{Z}/p_{n}\#$ is our inverse system of natural ring surjections (compose these consecutive ones to get all arrows in the system); we have that a unit in $L = \lim_{\leftarrow} R_n$ can be represented as a tuple:
$$
u = (u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4, \dots)
$$
where each $u_i \in U_i$ and $f_{i,i+1}(u_{i+1}) = u_i$ for all $i\geq 1$.
Now take the following diagram:

Note that if for $i = 1$ we put $A_1:= U_1$ and $i \gt 2$, $A_i := U_i \sqcup \{ p_2, \dots, p_i\}$, then $f_{j,i}(A_i) = A_j$ as each prime except for $p_i$ will map to itself (modulo respective moduli), and $p_i$ will into $U_i$ because it's a unit modulo its smaller primes.  Therefore, we have an inverse system of sets $A_i$ given by restrictions of the homomorphisms or $f_{i,j}|_{A_i}$.

Let $\Bbb{P}=$ the set of odd prime numbers.
Question. Let $U =$ the group of units of the inverse limit $L$ in the above.  Does $\Delta(U \sqcup \Bbb{P}) = \{ u - v : u,v \in U\sqcup \Bbb{P} \text{ and } - \text{ is done in the limiting ring}\} = \lim_{\leftarrow} \Delta(A_i)$?  In other words, does elementwise differencing $\Delta$ commute with inverse-limiting operation?

Notice, that primes are easily includable, but including some arbitrary sequence of odd numbers might not work out (be an inverse system).

Intuitively it should commute, I'm just needing help with formally / rigorously actually writing it down.

By Chinese remainders, your ring $L$ is just the product of all the $\mathbb{Z}/p$, and your $U$ is the product of the groups of units.

@DaveBenson, inverse limits of infinite sequences are generally certain subrings of the infinite product ring, not the whole product ring.  Notice that if you had $u
= (u_1, u_2, u_3, \dots)$ and $f_{3,2}(u_3) \neq u_2 \mod 3#$, which is possible in the product ring, then $u \notin$ the limit.

You've misunderstood my remark. The point is that if $p_1,\dots,p_n$ are distinct primes then by Chinese remainders, $\mathbb{Z}/p_n\dots p_1$ is isomorphic to the direct product $\mathbb{Z}/p_1 \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}/p_n$. So you're taking the inverse limit of the finite products, which gives you the infinite product.

@DaveBenson I just proved to you that it's not equal to the infinite product, so ...

@DaveBenson This limit ring does not equal $\prod_{n \geq 1} \Bbb{Z}/p_n#$, it's a strict subring of it

@DaveBenson $x =  (1,2, ...) \in \prod_i \Bbb{Z}/p_i#$ is an element of the product, but when you project $2$ into $\Bbb{Z}/p_1$, you get $0$, while clearly $x$'s first entry is $1$.  Are you telling me they are actually isomorphic somehow?

Hang on, I see what your confusion is. I'm taking the product of the $\mathbb{Z}/p$, not of the $\mathbb{Z}/p\sharp$.

There is no Chinese remaindering required to take $2 \in \Bbb{Z}/6$ and then projecting  onto $\Bbb{Z}/2$ or in other words taking $2$ modulo $2$, which is $0$.  I do know how CRT works, but thankfully I didn't need to apply it here.

I've given up, this is completely pointless. I've deleted some of my answers, leaving enough to explain it to you if you really want to understand. If you don't want to understand, I suppose that's up to you.

@DaveBenson  I have not figured out yet what point you are making.  Maybe you could provide a link?

The point I'm making is that although the limit is not the product of the $\mathbb{Z}/p#$, it is the product of the $\mathbb{Z}/p$. This does require use of the Chinese remainder theorem.

@DaveBenson I see that now... hmm. But what exactly is the isomorphism with the limit?  Because the limit has structured tuples (meaning the next maps onto the previous entry etc), while the product of all the $\Bbb{Z}/p$ doesn't have this property when viewed as similar tuples...  So that's where I'm confused.
But I think it's this.  $x \in (x_1, x_2, \dots) \in \prod_{i} \Bbb{Z}/p_i$ maps onto any $\Bbb{Z}/p_n#$ via projection.  Aha! This makes sense now

Okay, let me spell it out slowly. Take $\mathbb{Z}/6 \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ for example, given by reduction modulo two. If we write $\mathbb{Z}/6$ as $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/3$ using the Chinese remainder theorem, then the map is just projection onto the first factor. So the maps are written into the product via Chinese remainders. They're projection maps.

@DaveBenson what can we say about the elementwise difference operator and taking the limit?

The limit is isomorphic as a ring to the product ring. If you're asking whether differences in the infinite product can be done componentwise, then yes, of course.

@DaveBenson I think the answer may be no to this, because I'm finding it difficult to prove, also components in this product ring, I don't think correspond to components in the usual inverse-limit construction.  I'll try to make an answer.  In other words, if the answer is yes, I think it deserves a proof, because it's not as simple as component-wise differencing.

Readers, see comments on answer, it's harder than I thought it was to prove this, if it's even possible to prove.

Why was I automatically banned after even this post?  I should be welcomed not auto-banned.  Why does the internet have to be an exact replica of the real world?

In general let the $A_i$ be any subsets of $\Bbb{Z}/p_i\#$ such that all together they form an inverse-system, with maps that are restrictions of ring homomorphisms, respectively to each $A_i$.
Then $$A:= \Delta (\lim_{\longleftarrow} A_i) = \{ (u_i - v_i)_{i \geq 1} \in \prod_{n\geq 1}\Delta A_n: u_i, v_i \in A_i \wedge f_{i+1}(u_{i+1}) = u_i, \text{ sim. } v\}  \\
$$
Firstly, $\Delta A_i$ is an inverse-system as well.  Because $f_{i,i+1}|_{A_{i+1}} : A_{i+1} \to A_{i}$ takes elementwise differences to elementwise differences being a ring homomorphism restricted to subsets.
The limit is:
$$
B:= \lim_{\longleftarrow}(\Delta A_n) \\ = \{ (u_i - v_i)_{i\geq 1}\in \prod_{n\geq 1}\Delta A_n :u_i,v_i \in A_i \wedge f_{i,i+1}(u_{i+1} - v_{i+1}) = u_i - v_i\}
$$
I can see that $A \subset B$, but do we have the opposite inclusion?

Thanks @DaveBenson for the observation that the full ring limit is isomorphic to the product over all modular arithmetic fields (prime moduli):

For our chosen $\lim R_i$ representation (namely as that set of certain infinite tuples above), of course $u$ is then precisely the function $u(x = (x_i)_{i \geq 1} \in R = \lim R_i) := (\pi_{2}(x), \pi_{3}(x), \pi_{5}(x), \dots) \in \prod_{i} \Bbb{Z}/p_i$.
Similarly, the reverse isomorphism $!v:\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\Bbb{Z}/p_i \to \lim \Bbb{Z}/p_i\#$ must therefore be given by:
$$
v: (x_1, x_2, \dots) \mapsto (\langle \rho_i(x) : i\leq k \rangle)_{k \geq 1} 
$$
ie. each component is formed is of the product mapping formed from the first $k$ projections $\rho_i$.  This of course is onto $\Bbb{Z}/p_k\#$.
Now to verify, clearly $v(u(x)) = (\rho_{p_i}(u(x)):i\leq k)_{k\geq 1}) = (\pi_{p_k}(x))_{k \geq 1} = (x_1,x_2, \dots) = x$.
Conversely, $$u(v(x)) = ((\pi_{p_k}(v(x)))_{k \geq 1} =(\rho_{p_k})_{k\geq 1}(x)) = (x_1, x_2, \dots) = x$$
So to transform as @DavidBenson suggest the problem over to $\prod_{i \geq 1} \Bbb{Z}/p_i$ setting, I'm still working on it, but it will be by the above isomorphisms between the two rings.

@DaveBenson This is what I meant in the comments.  Maybe there's something I'm not seeing, but can't seem to prove equality here.

Please translate your question into a question about the infinite product, and you'll see what you're asking.

@DaveBenson I'll work on it and then post back here.  It would be very interesting to me if the difference subsets with ring hom restrictions do commute with categorical limit.

@DaveBenson could you give any more hints than this and thanks for your help thus far.   Essentially each time I want to prove it, I can't seem to show that $(x_i - y_i){i \geq 1} \in  B$ forms the whole set of $A$, even when each $f{i,i+1}$ is surjective, and I'm not even sure if that matters.  See above for $A, B$.  The goal is $A = B$.   Reason is, because differences in $\lim \Delta A_i$ could be formed from elements $x = (a -  b)$ but I can't guarantee that $a, b \in \lim A_i$... That is the rub of the problem.  Might require some kind of homological resolution property...

Did you translate into a question about the product?

@DaveBenson as you can see I tried to: I exhibited the isomorphism under which I would do it.  Let me try again
